# Adempiere webui 380 Barcode Scanning focus removed from scan fiield and Scanning product lines doesn't focused

Tags: java, adempiere

Adempiere webui 380 barcode scanning focus doesn't work. it removes the focus from scanning field everytime needs to put cursor manually there and scan. Secondly, it works fine in some machine and many machines it creates probelm. I have tried with clearing cache and history of browser. Also adempiere cahches removed.

Secondly, after scanning of product it doesn't focus on the line of which product scanning E.g. if there are 100 lines and if i am scanning line no 100 product, i have to scroll down and check manually quantities are udpated or not. on every scan cursor moved to first lines.

Comment: For ADempiere bugs and other support questions, it would be best to add an issue to the project GitHub project at https://github.com/adempiere/adempiere/issues.  You'll also find quicker project-specific help at https://gitter.im/adempiere/adempiere

Comment: Can you describe your scanning setup a little more?  Specifically, what key-codes are being used by the scanner prior to and following the scan.  There is a possibility that the scanner itself may be moving the focus.

Comment: snippet of class GridTabDataBinder.java which exists in zkwebui/WEB-INF/org/adempiere/webui/util/GridTabDataBinder.java.This code is in method 
  ' valueChange(ValueChangeEvent e).   if(e.getPropertyName().equals("ScanLocator_BizInt") ||e.getPropertyName().equals("Scan_SR_Barcode_BizInt") ||e.getPropertyName().equals("UPC_BizInt")||e.getPropertyName().equals("BarcodeInventory_BizInt")){    Object source = e.getSource();
if(source instanceof WStringEditor)
 { WStringEditor editor = (WStringEditor)source;
                  org.zkoss.zul.Textbox box =editor.getComponent();  '

Comment: Also like to share with you , i have tested the scanner with notepad and excel where it is doing proper enter to the next line or next cell for excel. Secondly I have analyzed it is working fine in my system which is having windows 7 but in system where it is not working is windows 10. Is it matters???

Comment: Happy to help if I can.  Generally, if you can enter the data by hand, the scanner should be able to do the same thing.  How the scanner deals with the focus is important - the scan is only part of it.  For example, <F2 to edit record><tab 8 times to get to the right field><enter the scanned data><Enter to bind it><F4 to save the record><Down arrow to get to the next record>.  Possible problems are adding a refresh (which could move the focus back to the top).  On different systems, it depends how the scanner was installed and setup.

Comment: Also tried by manual scan where i am entering data manually and press enter in my case, the result is it's removes the cursor from the scan field same as barcode does.Same barcode scanner  used by me to for scanning in one machine(windows 7 OS) where it works fine, only with that barcoce scanner it creating problem (windows 10 OS). Thanks Michael MCKay your opinions help to analzed more things

Comment: hi MichaelMcKay i hava analyzed this problem through code. A method called mTab.dataRefresh(); which i call while scan. It updated the line quantity in line, If i comment this code and  scan then it works fine and in every system it scan properly, but it doesn't update the line quantity we have to manually press refresh button in order to show updated quantity. I have tried all overloaded method of mTab.dataReferesh as some of fire event so, But those method doesn't helped me. Is there any other way to update line quantity without dataReferesh method, which doesn't involved events.